# Modify specific values within a JSON Object, return a cloned version of the object with modified values?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify an obj similar to this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "0923f8e0-d090-11ea-8615-9d076fb270e8",
      "pb_id": "or-portland-188",
      "state": "Oregon",
      "city": "Portland",
      "date": "2020-07-27T00:00:00.000000Z",
      "title": "Journalist shot in the face",
      "description": null,
      "data": null,
      "geocoding": { "lat": 45.5051064, "long": -122.6750261 }
    },
    {
    ...
    },
   ]
}
```

I need to go into every instance of the "geocoding" key, and modify the lat/long values slightly as all of the coordinates I have are identical.

I have a function to add a small amount of randomness, but I'm having trouble accessing the values and getting the entire object with modified values returned.

If you needed to go in and change all of the lat/long values (let's say multiply them all by 0 for demonstration sake), how would you do this?

EDIT:
This is my solution, thank you @cyberwombat

```
const newData = pbdb.data.map(item => {
  const x = item.geocoding.lat;
  const y = item.geocoding.long;
  return {
    ...item,
    geocoding: {
      lat: parseFloat(x) + 2 * 0.05 * (Math.random() - 0.5),
      long: parseFloat(y) + 2 * 0.05 * (Math.random() - 0.5),
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` through it like this:

```
const newData = data.map(item => {
  return { ...item, geocoding: { lat: 45.5051064 * 2, long: -122.6750261 * 2 } }
}
```

or with values unrelated to `item` - here I call external functions to randomize or do whatever:

```
// Some geo
const someLat = origLat => { 
  return 111 // could generate something random 
}
const someLong = origLong => { 
  return origLong * 2 // could generate something random 
}

const newData = data.map(item => {
  const { geocoding: { lat, long }} = item // Double spread...
  return { ...item, geocoding: { lat: someLat(lat), long: someLong(long) } }
}
```

Here's info on map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

And the spread operator to merge objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Ahh! Spread operator, that helps a bunch. I guess I shouldn't have said ALL values are identical, but a large number of them are. Can I do this without using the actual values in my map loop? something like { lat: x * 2, long: x * 2 }.

that would be ideal.

Comment: You can certainly use outside values if thats what you mean

Comment: @EthanHargrave added an example on using external functions - passing original data but options to do whatever.

Comment: const newData = pbdb.data.map(item => {
  const x = item.geocoding[0] 
  const y = item.geocoding[1]
  return { ...item, geocoding: { lat: parseFloat(x) * 2, long: parseFloat(y) * 2 } }
}
)

this is what I mean, values show up as NaN in newData

Comment: `geocoding[0]` is for arrays - thats an object. So `geocoding.lat`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```js
const { data } = {
  data: [
    {
      id: "0923f8e0-d090-11ea-8615-9d076fb270e8",
      pb_id: "or-portland-188",
      state: "Oregon",
      city: "Portland",
      date: "2020-07-27T00:00:00.000000Z",
      title: "Journalist shot in the face",
      description: null,
      data: null,
      geocoding: { lat: 45.5051064, long: -122.6750261 },
    },
  ],
}

const res = data.map((element) => {
  element.geocoding.lat += 1
  element.geocoding.long += 1
  // any other modification if have
  return element
})

console.log(res)
```